# Custom post type taxonomy template

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've created a custom post type `portfolio` and a `taxonomy` of course.

```
function taxonomies_portfolio() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Portfolio categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Portfolio categories', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Query portfolio categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All portfolio categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit portfolio category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update portfolio category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add Edit portfolio category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New portfolio category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_category', 'portfolio', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomies_portfolio', 0 );
```

Is it possible to create **1 template file to display all items of a single category?** I've tried to create a `taxonomy.php` but without success. What is the correct template name to work with?

Comment: I made a CPT `portfolio` and its categories `portfolio_categories`, I can see all the portfolio using `archive-portfolio.php`. And you can see your desired category items using `archive-portfolio_category.php` as your taxonomy is `portfolio_category`.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Thanks for your response. I've created a "archive-portfolio_category.php" and a "taxonomy-portfolio_category.php" without success. My WhatTheFile plugin still returns: archive.php

Comment: Register taxonomy function should be like this: `register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_category', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );` and rewrite parameter can be like this: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-categories' ),`

Comment: Sorry, in your case rewrite will be: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-category' ),`, don't forget to try `archive-portfolio-category.php` (hyphenated) too. Because I din't try this. :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Thanks for your effort - tested your code, updated the Permalinks, but it is still the same -> archive.php

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/27/customizing-wordpress-archives-categories-terms-taxonomies/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wordpress Codex page on [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), you create a template file with the name of `taxonomy-portfolio_category.php`.  WordPress will use that to display the archive for that taxonomy.  You can also use `taxonomy-portfolio_category-{term_name}.php` to create templates for specific terms in your taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks Manny, but is it possible to use 1 template for all categories instead of creating 3 templates for 3 categories?

Comment: Yeah, the first part of my answer :  taxonomy-portfolio_category.php

Comment: Ok, thanks Manny - but unfortunately it didn't work, is there still something to consider?

Comment: Whats not working? How are you testing it?

Comment: I've tested "taxonomy-portfolio_category.php", but it displays archive.php instead.

Comment: Using what url?

Comment: Nice idea, I'm using: url/category/books/ Is that wrong?

Comment: For your taxonomy, it should be portfolio_category/books

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the WordPress standard tempates to manage the several taxonomies' templates for the same custom post type.

Assume you have your: 1) `portfolio` CPT with the 1) `pcat` taxonomy and 3) 'sites', 'apps' and 'design' terms created in this taxonomy (here slugs are shown).

**Case 1:** You may want to show the same template for any of these `pcat` taxonomies. Just use the same single `portfolio-signle.php` template with the code that shows any single `portfolio` record in a uniform way.

**Case 2:** Now say you want to show different template for each `portfolio` CPT record depending on the `pcat` taxonomy term ('sites', 'apps', 'design', 'whatever') assigned to that record.

You can do this still using the same `portfolio-signle.php` with additional partial template for each `pcat` term.

Your `portfolio-signle.php` has to hold this code:

```
<?php
get_header();
// Here you get the particular record of the `portfolio` CPT.
global $post;
// Get the array of 'pcat' taxonomy terms attached to the record
// and take the slug of first term only (just for brevity)
$txslug = get_the_terms($post, 'pcat')[0]->slug;
// Dynamically prepare the file name
$filename = get_template_directory() . '/partials/_portfolio-single-'.$txslug.'.php';
// Check if the file exists & readable
if (is_readable($filename)) {
    // The case when you  created the sub-template partial for the particular `pcat` term.
    include get_template_directory() . '/partials/_portfolio-single-'.$txslug.'.php';
} else {
    // The case for all other `pcat` taxonomy terms.
    include get_template_directory() . '/partials/_portfolio-single-other.php';
}
get_footer();
```

As you see from the code above you will have to create the respective partial sub-templates for each `pcat` taxonomy term you assign to your posts that will actually handle the look of the taxonomy term.

Or / and create the `/partials/portfolio-single-other.php` to handle all the terms that you want to look uniform way.

This will keep your theme files well-organized and for at no code cost allow you flexibly manage the look of the different taxonomy terms'.

NB: Do not forget to re-declare `global $post;` at the top of your `'/partials/_portfolio-single-'.$txslug.'.php'` templates. You will get the access to the CPT object you want to show at no additional costs.